Como puede Hacer, para que mi input cuando coloco un numero me aparezca automáticamente en un label y multiplicado por un numero que yo quiera. con js
Estoy haciendo un sistema de rifas, entonces el cliente debe colocar cuantas boletas necesita y así mismo aparezca el valor abajo ya multiplicado con el valor de la boleta Instantáneamente. LE AGRADECERIA DE ANTEMANO CUALQUIER AYUDA.

Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento.

En HTML, lo básico que necesitas es:

Un elemento tipo <input> para capturar el número de boletos de la transacción. A este elemento asociaremos la función que prepararemos en javascript al evento onChange, de manera que esta función se lance cada vez que cambie su valor.
Un elemento capaz de representar texto en la salida para mostrar el total. En los ejemplos a continuación yo usaré un <span>
Colocar un id a cada elemento, que debe ser único para cada uno, de manera que sean fácilmente accesibles desde javascript.

Luego, del lado de javascript, lo básico es

obtener una referencia a los elementos en el DOM para poder acceder a ellos. Esto lo haré con el método getElementById() del documento.
leer la cantidad, accediendo a la propiedad value del input.
realizar el cálculo del total
asignar el valor de dicho cálculo a la salida del elemento total, valiéndonos de su propiedad innerText.

Con esta explicación, el código hablarte por sí solo:


const elmCantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad");
const elmTotal = document.getElementById("total");

function calcularTotal() {
  let cantidad = elmCantidad.value;
  let total = cantidad * 10;
  elmTotal.innerText = total;
}
<input type="number" id="cantidad" onChange="calcularTotal()" onKeyUp="calcularTotal()" onKeyDown="calcularTotal()"><br>
<span id="total">0.00</span>



Una interfaz de usuario más elaborada, tendrá algunas validaciones, mostrará más elementos y se garantizará de mostrar siempre resultados consistentes.
Para ello, además de agregar algunos elementos visuales adicionales, ahora tendré el valor del precio unitario en una variable, mostraré el precio unitario al usuario y, además, me aseguraré de formatear correctamente los valores de acuerdo a la moneda en la que se realice la transacción. Los elementos centrales son los mismos que ya se han explicado antes, pero ahora nos valemos de una instancia de Intl.NumberFormat para lograr un formato apropiado para los números.


const precioUnitario = 10.00;
const elmPrecioUnitario = document.getElementById("precioUnitario");
const elmCantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad");
const elmTotal = document.getElementById("total");
const currFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-GT', {style: 'currency', currency: 'GTQ',});

function calcularTotal() {
  let cantidad = elmCantidad.value;
  let total = 0;
  if (cantidad > 0) total = cantidad * precioUnitario;
  elmTotal.innerText = currFormatter.format(total);
}

elmPrecioUnitario.innerText = currFormatter.format(precioUnitario);
calcularTotal();
<div>
  <h3>Venta de boletos</h3>
  <p>Valor del boleto: <span id="precioUnitario">0.00</span></p>
  <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label><input type="number" value="1" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" min="1" onChange="calcularTotal()"  onKeyUp="calcularTotal()" onKeyDown="calcularTotal()">
  <p>Total: <span id="total">10.00</span></p>
</div>




exactamente, pero podría yo colocar el numero en el input y me arroje el resultado sin dar Enter.

Claro, eso no era mencionado en tu pregunta, pero Puedes asociar el evento onKeyUp, que se lanza cada vez que el usuario deja de presionar una tecla.

@Carlos, edité la respuesta para incluir los eventos del teclado.
